# First android app won't install

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've followed the instructions at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I can't seem to get the app to install.

My console output:

```
[2013-03-30 12:30:41 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-03-30 12:30:41 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-30 12:30:41 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity     activity launch
[2013-03-30 12:30:41 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with     compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
[2013-03-30 12:30:41 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
```

As seen, there are no 'installing apk' messages, or anything to indicate that Eclipse is loading my app onto the emulator. I also cannot find my app on the emulator once it starts up.

Running this project under the following config:

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Eclipse Version: Indigo Release

Android Development Toolkit Version: 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Log from logcat shows the following. Is this normal?

```
03-30 08:41:48.010: W/Trace(779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-30 08:41:48.039: I/Choreographer(779): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-30 08:41:48.079: W/Trace(779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-30 08:41:48.079: W/Trace(779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: you say emulator has started in that case your console output is not complete

Comment: That is all the output I have in my console.

Comment: can you restart eclipse and emulator and retry again? is it the same? have you tried what other two guys saying here?

Comment: I have tried restarting everything, including my computer. No change. And yes, I have tried what the other guys have said and left comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the problem was. I was initially using my existing Eclipse IDE for Android development.

Downloading the Full ADT from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html fixed the problem. Which leads me to believe that the SDK was not playing nicely with my old Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the emulator fully started up and then.
1.Clean your project by Project->clean
2.Then right click project Run As-> Android application
Try the above and reply whats happening

Comment: No change, still the same thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your emulator gets displayed under Devices tab

window->show view->devices

Comment: No, the emulator is not displayed under 'Devices'. Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes. If you don't see any device here that means your emulator isn't running.

Comment: But the emulator window pops up and boots, and I can see the home screen and everything.

Answer (score 0):

try to launch your AVD manager...and in it check the wipe user data checkbox...and relaunch your app from eclipse...give it a try and tell if it works

Comment: and donot forget to clean your project

Comment: Nope, still no difference.

Comment: what is your minimum api version...for app

Comment: `    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

Comment: try creating a new emulator with your desired configurations...delete old emulator and choose the new emulator while launching

Comment: When creating a new device I have only have the options "Android 4.2 - API level 17" and "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17" as options. Is that okay?

Comment: try testing on some lower apis like api-11 or api-12...you can download them from SDK manager...try them